# c# XmlElment change order in derived class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize a XML. I want to add a new property in a derived class and place it between the other properties of the base class.

In the sample I want to place the 'SpecialInterests' between the 'Name' and the 'Age' of the base class.

### XML

```
<!-- Output -->
    <PersonenListe xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <PersonenArray>
        <PersonObjekt>
          <Name>Max Man</Name>
          <Age>33</Age>
        </PersonObjekt>
        <PersonObjekt xsi:type="SpecialPerson">
          <Name>Albert Einstein</Name>
          <Age>36</Age>
          <SpecialInterests>Physics</SpecialInterests>
        </PersonObjekt>
      </PersonenArray>
    </PersonenListe>

<!-- Desire -->
    <PersonenListe>
      <PersonenArray>
        <PersonObjekt>
          <Name>Max Man</Name>
          <Age>33</Age>
        </PersonObjekt>
        <PersonObjekt xsi:type="SpecialPerson">
          <Name>Albert Einstein</Name>
          <SpecialInterests>Physics</SpecialInterests>
          <Age>36</Age>
        </PersonObjekt>
      </PersonenArray>
    </PersonenListe>
```

### c# - Main (Creating instances and serialization)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PersonalList personen = new PersonalList();
        Person normPerson = new Person { Name = "Max Man", Age = 33 };
        SpecialPerson specPerson = new SpecialPerson 
        { Name = "Albert Einstein", Interests = "Physics", Age = 36 };

        personen.AddPerson(normPerson);
        personen.AddPerson(specPerson);

        Type[] personTypes = new Type[personen.Persons.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < personen.Persons.Count; i++)
        {
            personTypes[i] = personen.Persons[i].GetType();
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonalList), personTypes);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("Personenliste.xml", FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(fs, personen);
        fs.Close();
        personen = null;

        // Deserialize 
        fs = new FileStream("Personenliste.xml", FileMode.Open);
        personen = (PersonalList)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, personen);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

### Models

```
[XmlRoot("PersonenListe")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Person))]
public class PersonalList
{
    [XmlArray("PersonenArray")]
    [XmlArrayItem("PersonObjekt")]
    public List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();

    public void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        Persons.Add(person);
    }
}

[XmlType("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", Order = 1)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Age", Order = 3)]
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
}


[XmlType("SpecialPerson")]
public class SpecialPerson : Person
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", Order = 1)]
    public override string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SpecialInterests", Order = 2)]
    public string Interests { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Age", Order = 3)]
    public override int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Serialization Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018490/net-serialization-ordering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is essentially the same this other question. There is a good explanation of why this serialization behavior is the way it is and a few approaches for dealing with it.

[.NET Serialization Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018490/net-serialization-ordering)

Comment: Thank you for sharing, i came up with a simpular solution, but I hoped that there might be a better solution.
(Sorry, can't give an upvote, because I don't have 15 Points..)