# Order XML elements for serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have to serialize my objects to a XML document in a certain order.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<__Root __version="1.1" __encryption="2">
  <__service __serviceType="Test">
  <__inputData>
   <BaseToChange>
    <__name>TestName</__name>
   </BaseToChange>
  </__inputData>
  <__perform> 
   <__eventName>Event</__eventName>
  </__perform>    
  <__inputData>
      <ObjectChanges>
        <Name>Test</Name>
      </ObjectChanges>
    </__inputData>
    <__execute />
    <__requestData>
      <CompletionMsg />
    </__requestData>
  </__service>
</__Root>
```

The problem I have now is that I'm not able to serialize my `List<InputData>`   with the Element `Perform` in between.

```
public class Service
{
    [XmlAttribute("__serviceType")]
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("__perform")]
    public Perform Perform { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("__inputData")]
    public List<InputData> InputData{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("__execute")]
    public Execute Execute { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("__requestData")]
    public RequestData RequestData{ get; set; }

    public Service() { }
}
```

The order has to be as shown. So first `<__inputData>`, then `<__perform>`, followed by any remaining `<__inputData>`.

I already tried to separate the Properties and therefore the XmlElements but as soon I want to serialize with two elements having the same name I get an error.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018490/net-serialization-ordering

Comment: What do you mean in between? do you mean item 1 of the list and then perform and then item 2 in the list? it sounds like your structure should be redesigned

Comment: @Ofir Winegarden: Exactly. I need this structure otherwise the system I try to create an object in (via XML) throws an error.

Comment: 1) How do you want to control where the `<__perform>` element appears?  It is always after the first `<__inputData>` or can it vary?  2) What does your `InputData` type look like?  It seems it sometimes has a `<BaseToChange>` element, and sometimes an `<ObjectChanges>` element?

Comment: The order has to be as shown. So first `<__inputData>`, then <__perform>`` followed by `<__inputData>`. The type of 'InputData' has indeed the two objects: `BaseToChange` and `ObjectChanges`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the polymorphic element functionality [`[XmlElement(Type = typeof(TElement))]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.type.aspx) to create a surrogate object array that contains both the `Perform` and `InputData` objects, in the correct sequence:

```
public class Service
{
    [XmlAttribute("__serviceType")]
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Perform Perform { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<InputData> InputData { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("__perform", Type = typeof(Perform))]
    [XmlElement("__inputData", Type = typeof(InputData))]
    public object[] XmlInputAndPerformance
    {
        get
        {
            var inputData = (InputData ?? Enumerable.Empty<InputData>()).Cast<object>();
            var performData = Perform == null ? Enumerable.Empty<object>() : new object[] { Perform };

            return inputData.Take(1)
                .Concat(performData)
                .Concat(inputData.Skip(1))
                .ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            var newInputs = value.OfType<InputData>().ToList();
            var newPerform = value.OfType<Perform>().ToList();
            if (newInputs.Count + newPerform.Count != value.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown type.");
            if (newPerform.Count > 1)
                throw new ArgumentException("Too many Perform objects.");

            if (newPerform.Count > 0)
                Perform = newPerform[0];
            (InputData = InputData ?? new List<InputData>()).AddRange(newInputs);
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("__execute")]
    public Execute Execute { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("__requestData")]
    public RequestData RequestData { get; set; }

    public Service() { }
}
```

Note that the original `InputData` and `Perform` properties have been marked with [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) and that two `[XmlElement(name, Type = typeof(TElement))]` attributes have been added, one for `InputData` and one for `Perform`.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QBaSdt).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.