# How to decide order of xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have generic base class which has property body and another derived class which has property header and when i deserialize the derived class into xml its placing the body as first element first then header (deserializing in alphabetical order) but I want header first and then Body. I have tried XmlElement's order property but its not working

Sample class:

```
[XmlRoot("BaseClass", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class BaseClass<T>
{
   public T Body { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("DerivedClass", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class DerivedClass<THeader, TBody> : BaseClass<TBody>
where THeader : IEnvelopeHeader where TBody : class, IEnvelopeBody, new()
{
    public THeader Header { get; set; }
}
```

I saw one solution which says that make the property in base class as abstract and override in derived class then decide the order but i cann't go with this solution which my base class is used in some other projects as well.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018490/net-serialization-ordering

Comment: Yeldar thanks for reply but it seems that approach isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the order issue for now by removing the inheritance but that's not what i wanted to achieve, All I need is to order the xml element as per the order defined even when you are using inheritance chain.

```
[XmlRoot("Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope<THeader, TBody>
where THeader : IEnvelopeHeader where TBody : class, IEnvelopeBody, new()
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Order = 1)]
    public THeader Header { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Order = 2)]
    public TBody Body { get; set; }
}
```