HTTP nested variable JSON response to collection or SQL using vb.net
I am trying to write a backup program for a bunch of data in our CRM, because its native version lacks quite a bit of information we want secured. I'm needing to use vb.net (.Net Framework 4.8.1), and my end goal is mapping to a SQL server with a host of tables once I figure out exactly what values we're backing up. The call is an HTTP GET, and the response is in nested JSON. Beyond that I want to back up as much as I can, and I don't really care what methods/nuget packages (as long as reputable)/whatever I have to use to get there. I've never dealt with JSON before and I'm frankly in over my head.
The data is extremely variable and huge- there could be as many as 300 main properties, most of which keep version history, but not all. Blank values don't appear to be returned, so the response is a bit unpredictable in structure.
Basic structure heavily anonymized:
{
  "vid": 12345,
  "canonical-vid": 12345,
  "merged-vids": [],
  "portal-id": 12345678,
  "is-contact": true,
  "properties": {
    "prop1": {
      "value": "12345678",
      "versions": [
        {
          "value": "12345678",
          "source-type": "CALCULATED",
          "source-id": "source1",
          "source-label": null,
          "updated-by-user-id": null,
          "timestamp": 1717375078168,
          "selected": false,
          "data-sensitivity": null,
          "is-encrypted": null
        },
        {
          "value": "12345678;12345679",
          "source-type": "CALCULATED",
          "source-id": "source1",
          "source-label": null,
          "updated-by-user-id": null,
          "timestamp": 1711381559120,
          "selected": false,
          "data-sensitivity": null,
          "is-encrypted": null
        },
        {
          "value": "12345679",
          "source-type": "CALCULATED",
          "source-id": "source1",
          "source-label": null,
          "updated-by-user-id": null,
          "timestamp": 1711037348472,
          "selected": false,
          "data-sensitivity": null,
          "is-encrypted": null
        },
        {
          "value": "12345679;12345680",
          "source-type": "CALCULATED",
          "source-id": "source1",
          "source-label": null,
          "updated-by-user-id": null,
          "timestamp": 1711027558111,
          "selected": false,
          "data-sensitivity": null,
          "is-encrypted": null
        },
        {
          "value": "12345681",
          "source-type": "CALCULATED",
          "source-id": "source1",
          "source-label": null,
          "updated-by-user-id": null,
          "timestamp": 1710899316341,
          "selected": false,
          "data-sensitivity": null,
          "is-encrypted": null
        }
      ]
    },
    "prop2": {
      "value": "https://myurl.com/contact/",
      "versions": [
        {
          "value": "https://myurl.com/contact/",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "source2",
          "source-label": null,
          "updated-by-user-id": null,
          "timestamp": 1685656187542,
          "selected": false,
          "data-sensitivity": null,
          "is-encrypted": null
        },
        {
          "value": "https://myurl.com/page 2/",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "source2",
          "source-label": null,
          "updated-by-user-id": null,
          "timestamp": 1685656121699,
          "selected": false,
          "data-sensitivity": null,
          "is-encrypted": null
        }
      ]
    },
'...continue like this for a variable amount of properties with a variable amount of nested versions each, though all the versions sections have the same properties, then finish off with the below...
},
  "form-submissions": [
    {
      "conversion-id": "alphanumeric_string",
      "timestamp": 1685656111147,
      "form-id": "alphanumeric_string",
      "portal-id": 12345678,
      "page-url": "https://myurl.com/form page/",
      "page-title": "My Page Title",
      "title": "#gform_2 .form",
      "form-type": "CAPTURED",
      "meta-data": []
    }
  ],
  "list-memberships": [],
  "identity-profiles": [
    {
      "vid": 12345,
      "saved-at-timestamp": 1685656112544,
      "deleted-changed-timestamp": 0,
      "identities": [
        {
          "type": "EMAIL",
          "value": "email@domain.com",
          "timestamp": 1685656111147,
          "is-primary": true
        },
        {
          "type": "LEAD_GUID",
          "value": "alphanumeric_string",
          "timestamp": 1685656112534
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "merge-audits": []
}


I'm thinking the version history sections are regular enough I can handle those by mapping to a SQL table with fields:
ID int identity no null, 
ObjType varchar(32) no null, 
ObjID int no null,
Prop varchar(128) no null,
value varchar no null,
sourceType varchar no null,
sourceId varchar null,
sourceLabel varchar null,
updatedByUserID varchar null,
timestamp varchar no null,
selected boolean no null,
dataSensitivity varchar null,
isEncrypted boolean null

I want to get to the point where I can say something like
Dim Fields as string = ""
Dim Values as string = ""
Dim VerHistory as List(Of VerHistoryCustomClass)
For Each prop as JsonMember in JsonObject
  Fields &= prop.Name & ","
  Values &= prop.Value & ","
  If (some test for presence of version history) Then
    dim hist as new VerHistoryCustomClass(variables...)
    VerHistory.Add(hist)
  End If
End For

SQLComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO objTable (" & Fields & ")
VALUES (" & Values & ")"
SQLcon.Open()
SQLcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()

For Each ver as VerHistoryCustomClass in VerHistory
  SQLcomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO verTable VALUES (" & ver.toCommaDelimitedString & ")"
  SQLcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
End For

SQLcon.Close()

or its similar update version if the ID was already there.
I'm just really struggling getting from the returned JSON to something I can start assigning to variables. I also don't know how to necessarily deal with the last few properties that break the pattern and have nested structures of their own.
Here's some of my trying to get the JSON back and dealing with it:
IMPORTS RestSharp
Public Class Test_Area
    Private ReadOnly HttpClientTest As New HttpClient
    Friend ReadOnly EndptContactsAllData As String = "https://apiurl.com/endpt"
    Private Async Sub btnTestGetSpecificContact_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestGetSpecificContact.Click
        'Dim testclient As HttpClient = GetCrmClient() 'adds headers if not there
        'Dim email As String = "person@domain.com"
        'Dim fullUri = EndptContactsAllData & "/contact/email/" & email & "/profile"
        'Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await testclient.GetAsync(fullUri)
        'If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        '    Dim pause = True
        '    Dim raw = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        '    'Using jDoc As JsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(raw)
        '    '    Dim JRtElement As JsonElement = jDoc.RootElement
        '    '    pause = True
        '    'End Using
        'Else
        'End If
        Dim email As String = "person@domain.com"
        Dim fullUri = EndptContactsAllData & "/contact/email/" & email & "/profile"
        Dim testclient As New RestClient(fullUri)
        Dim testReq As New RestRequest(Method.GET)
        testReq.AddHeaders(GetCrmClientHeaders) 'GetCrmClientHeaders returns dictionary(Of string, string) for header values
        Dim testResponse As IRestResponse = Await testclient.ExecuteAsync(testReq)
        If testResponse.IsSuccessful Then
            'handle returned JSON
        Else
            'handle error codes
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCrmClient() As HttpClient
        If HttpIsInitialized = False Then
            HttpClientTest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json")
            HttpClientTest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", "Bearer " & AccessToken)
        End If
        Return HttpClientTest
    End Function

    Public Function GetCrmClientHeaders() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim hdrDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        hdrDict.Add("accept", "application/json")
        hdrDict.Add("authorization", "Bearer " & AccessToken)
        Return hdrDict

    End Function
END Class

I know this is a lot, I can use any suggestions of where to start that you can give.
Edit: Added .Net version (.Net Framework 4.8.1)

As an addendum: the restSharp version currently is 106.15.0 in order to get more examples on the internet as the newer 112.1.0 I'm having a harder time getting through the documentation for, and couldn't find where to add the headers.

I am trying to write a backup program for a bunch of data: Why have you chosen to use a database for this?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65280075/10024425

TBH this doesn't sound like a backup (and restore) process or you'd probably just be storing the JSON blob somewhere. So what's the purpose in trying to parse and shred it, are you actually wanting to replicate the data somewhere for reporting purposes?

You should consider creating classes that match your JSON structure and deserialize the JSON into objects.

@AlwaysLearning yes, this is partially for reporting purposes, but it's also because of API limits so I want to be selective about what I pull as delta/changes only updates later. I was planning on having a table with timestamps for when each object table was last fetched/updated, and then with the recent object calls that have paging I can stop when I get past that point. We're also very very not used to JSON so I'm not familiar with best practices concerning them.

For all, everything I've read so far doesn't allow me to create classes if the schema is unknown/unstable, and there are constant changes to even the properties in the CRM due to an onboarding process going on. I also don't think the properties being returned are consistent, as I don't see nulls and I am almost positive there are null properties for this test contact, so I don't think I'm getting those.

@Itallmakescents probably honestly I'm using SQL for backup because that's how everything else in-house is backed up. We heavily use SQL, and have even written programs to help people write fancy SQL reports with triggers to send them and such. It allows us to leverage the most existing code, and the reports can combine the info from our other systems and the backup for less time-sensitive reports to heavily reduce API calls and gain a lot of flexibility/refinement not currently available in the native platform or API as best I can tell.

If you're dealing with unknown schemas, probably the best is just to save raw json string with some metadata and then you can parse it for what you need later during downtime. Your question is very broad though, it's unclear if the issue is reading data from erp, saving it, parsing json or something else

@siggemannen I can't just save the raw json string. As already described above, that would be useless for reports, that would maximize API calls, and doesn't work with our existing backup infrastructure. This is being done daily, so parsing it later manually during downtime is unacceptable, particularly when we're talking tens of thousands of entries like this, just for this object, ignoring the other objects I also need to back up. My issue I thought I made clear, is that while I can get it to the point of a JSON, I need to be able to parse that for everything else to work.

If you're using string concatenation to put fields into an SQL string, you're doing it wrong and need to spend some time researching parameterized queries. This is a huge win for security, reliability, and performance.

@JoelCoehoorn I'm aware of parameterized SQL and use it often. You're not allowed to specify fields or tables that way to my knowledge. I will try to refactor this real quick to see if they've added that ability.

You should be able to convert all your JSON into objects using the JsonSerializer class. First you create classes that represent your JSON. Here are some partial classes I created to handle the JSON you posted in your question:
Public Class MainClass

    <JsonPropertyName("vid")>
    Public Property Vid As Integer?

    <JsonPropertyName("canonical-vid")>
    Public Property CanonicalVid As Integer?

    <JsonPropertyName("merged-vids")>
    Public Property MergedVids As List(Of Object)

    <JsonPropertyName("is-contact")>
    Public Property IsContact As Boolean?

    <JsonPropertyName("properties")>
    Public Property Properties As Dictionary(Of String, PropertyClass)

End Class

Public Class PropertyClass

    <JsonPropertyName("value")>
    Public Property Value As String

    <JsonPropertyName("versions")>
    Public Property Versions As List(Of VersionClass)

End Class

Public Class VersionClass

    <JsonPropertyName("value")>
    Public Property Value As String

    <JsonPropertyName("source-type")>
    Public Property SourceType As String

    <JsonPropertyName("source-id")>
    Public Property SourceId As String

    <JsonPropertyName("timestamp")>
    Public Property TimeStamp As Long?

End Class

These are not complete, you will want to add the remaining properties to each class, but they should get you on your way.
Once your classes are defined, you can use the deserializer to convert your JSON into a MainClass object:
Dim json As String
Using reader As New StreamReader("c:\temp\new 1.json")
    json = reader.ReadToEnd
End Using

Dim main As MainClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of MainClass)(json)

You can then access all the data through the main object's properties.

wait... that property class... and the list.... you mean I don't actually have to know how many properties it'll give me back? You may have just completely solved it for me if so.

Yes, the Dictionary and the List will handle any number of child nodes. A Dictionary is used because your Properties nodes are named. This will not work if you have duplicate names (like prop1 twice) though, but I don't think that's the case here. Also, this will also work if there are missing properties. For example, if one of the version nodes was missing the source-label property, the String value would be Nothing.
Please consider marking this answer as Accepted if it has answered your question.

this is definitely my best lead, but I haven't gotten it working yet and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to create the class, but while I understand why you would want to specify the json property name, the code you have there to do so isn't parsing and instead is coming up with "JsonPeropertyName is not defined". In case it matters, because I don't seem to be able to get the microsoft page to stay in the correct framework for the jsondeserializer, I'm using .net Framework 4.8.1

nevermind I was missing an Imports. About to build it out and try it, I'll definitely mark the answer accepted if it works. Regardless, I've already learned quite a bit from this answer, thank you.

I think you will have to install the System.Text.Json NuGet package. The package supports .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions. I would recommend upgrading your project to .NET 8 if possible.

@Éttienne Laneville This is almost working! The versions section is giving me a little trouble now. It's wanting to be a numeric type, but setting it to integer makes it crash on being passed null values. How can I safely handle this error, as it's common-most of the versions are due to some kind of automation instead of direct user intervention.

@CarrierPigeon you can make the Integer nullable by declaring it as Integer?. Same with Long and Boolean properties. You can also use Nullable variables for Dictionary and List. Wherever you could get a null, you should use a Nullable variable. If the JSON value is null, the property will have a value of Nothing. Answer has been updated to reflect this.

@Éttienne Laneville That did it! And I learned yet something else for dealing with nulls. I would vote this up further on top of marking it as the answer, but I don't have the rep yet. Thank you so much!
