# change order of xmlserialization with inherited class from base class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I have 2 classes. A base class and a extended class that inherit from this base class. When I want to serialize the extended class the order isn't correct.

```
public class BaseClass
{
   [XmlElement("B", Order = 2)]
   public string? B { get; init; }

   [XmlElement("C", Order = 3)]
   public string? C { get; init; }
}

public class ExtClass : BaseClass
{
   [XmlElement("A", Order = 1)]
   public string? A { get; init; }
}
```

The output when I serialise this is: B C A

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN) msdn article that is expected behavior and in other old links they suggest you can write your own serializer to combat this issue.

Is there an easier solution available to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you care about the order of properties in the XML output in the first place?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Because the receiving party(not me) expects them in order  (xsd:sequence) and I can't change that.

Comment: Can you show the XSD schema, because standard XSD would require extending types to suffix all new properties, rather than interleave.

Comment: @Proliges - your [doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order) is for `DataContractSerializer` not `XmlSerializer`, but `XmlSerializer` works the same way.  See [.NET Serialization Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1018490) for why and for some possible workarounds.  Does that answer your question?  Because the alternative would be implementing `IXmlSerializable` on `ExtClass`, or replacing `ExtClass` with some DTO.